# Gulp Watch Not Working and No Errors Thrown

Tags: gulp

I am working with a gulp configuration that I migrated to use gulp 4 and use `browserSync`, but I can't get the build and watch to work. I am able to get `browserSync` up and running, but none of the changes I am making within my `scss` directory are being updated and there aren't errors showing that indicate the code is wrong. Anything stand out as off with my configuration?

I am running `gulp watch` to launch the configuration.

Here is the output:

```
> gulp watch

[12:19:58] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/Projects/node/theme-kit/gulpfile.js
[12:19:58] Starting 'watch'...
[12:19:58] Starting 'browserSync'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3012
    External: http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3012
 -------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
```

Here is my `gulp.js`:

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  sass = require("gulp-sass"),
  sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps"),
  cleanCss = require("gulp-clean-css"),
  rename = require("gulp-rename"),
  postcss = require("gulp-postcss"),
  autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer"),
  browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

gulp.task("browserSync", function() {
  browserSync.init({
    port: 3012,
    server: {
      baseDir: "./",
      port: 3011
    }
  });
});

gulp.task("build-theme", function() {
  return gulp
    .src(["scss/*.scss"])
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(
      postcss([
        autoprefixer({
          browsers: [
            "Chrome >= 35",
            "Firefox >= 38",
            "Edge >= 12",
            "Explorer >= 10",
            "iOS >= 8",
            "Safari >= 8",
            "Android 2.3",
            "Android >= 4",
            "Opera >= 12"
          ]
        })
      ])
    )
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("css/"))
    .pipe(cleanCss())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: ".min" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("css/"))
    .pipe(
      browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
      })
    );
});

gulp.task("watch", gulp.series("browserSync", "build-theme", function() {
  gulp.watch(["scss/*.scss"], ["build-theme"]);
}));

gulp.task("default", gulp.series("watch", function() {}));
```

Comment: If you're on a Node version that is 14 or higher then `gulp.watch` doesn't work. Unknown if this is due to the `chokidar` instance or some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little surprised this line does not give you an error:

```
gulp.watch(["scss/*.scss"], ["build-theme"]);
```

change to:

```
gulp.watch("scss/*.scss", gulp.series("build-theme"));
```

and the following is unnecessarily complicated, but probably not technically an error:

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.series("watch", function() {}));
```

simplify to:

```
gulp.task("default", gulp.series("watch"));
```